# List the locale without making duplicates

Tags: bash, sed, locale

I would like to list all the locale names from the file `/etc/locale.gen` without having duplicates. I don't really know how to do it.

I've started removing the top of the file like so :

```
sed -n -e '/aa_DJ/,$p' /etc/locale.gen
```

It prints me all line. And I would like to have the output like so :

```
[...]
fr_FR
en_US
en_GB
[...]
```

Without the # and without the rest of what's after fr_FR for example. In one single command.

## EDIT 1 :

I may have found something with grep :

```
sed -n -e '/aa_DJ/,$p' /etc/locale.gen | grep {,1}
```

## EDIT 2 :

here is the file http://pastebin.com/i227sTV2

Comment: That pastebin link doesn't work. Even if it did (for now), the question should be complete *here*, i.e., containing all the information required to answer it.

Comment: well, the file contain more than 200 lines so... I'll try to change the file

Comment: The point is to create a representative excerpt of that file to show it as part of the question, see [mcve]. You don't need more than a few lines to show what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk -F "[ .@]" '/_|eo|ia/{sub("^# *",""); print $1}' /etc/locale.gen | sort -u
```

The "[ .@]" removes all after `language_country` (en_US).

---

A source locale.gen file is [packaged by debian here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/locales) (as an example of the file you should have, not needed to run the command above). A full list of locales is in the extracted (from the compressed deb file) file `/locales_2.22-5_all/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` (it contains 281 unique locale names).

Updated: `s/gsub/sub/g`  should run on any awk.

Comment: It displays the `#` that I wouldn't get in the desired output. Also it doesn't sort them nor it removes duplicates

Comment: It almost works, just have to remove the # at the begining.

Comment: @Gradiuss The `sub` removes the `#`. I changed it to accept *optional* spaces. Added sort. Sorting inside awk is not "one liner".

Comment: Please, give a cross-distribution/platform solution. I may be able to recompile your .deb package on my archlinux but it's too much hassle.

Comment: @Gradiuss The only thing you need to do is copy paste the awk line (the whole line) in a shell console and execute it. It should list all locales to the shell console.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for taking some time for resolving that one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
awk -F'[@. ]' '$1!="#"{sub(/^#/,"");print $1}' /etc/locale.gen | uniq
```

*(or the same without the `@`)*

Comment: Thanks for helping friend. Unfortunately, the output was not what I was expecting. I need all locale names, not only FR ones.

Comment: @Gradiuss: post an excerpt of your file in your question (I don't have this one on my system)

Comment: I've managed to do so with `awk -F'[.]' '{ print $1 }' /etc/locale.gen | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/#//g' | sort | uniq` but isn't there a way to make it with full awk ?